# how to insert image and hyperlink [ckeditor 4]

Tags: ckeditor

i have ckeditor looking like this 
[image]

i want that my ck-editor can insert hyperlink and image.like this

[image]

i've tried to search in documentation but i dont understand because its in english. and its hard for me to understand because im new for frontend

anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Download Full or Standard package from [CKEditor download page](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/). This package has both plugins you need.
2. It is possible that you are using Standard or Full packages already. You can verify that by opening `ckeditor/build-config.js` file and searching for `preset` word. If there is `full` or `standard` next to it, you have the right package and most likely you have changed your configuration. You may have used [removeButtons](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-removeButtons) or [removeplugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-removePlugins) settings where you remove `Link` and `Image` buttons or `link` and `image` plugins. You could have also used custom [toolbar](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-toolbar) definition where you haven't added `Link` and `Image` buttons or you are missing `links` and `insert` groups. If you wish to learn more about toolbar concepts, please see:https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_toolbarconcepts.html and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_toolbar.html.